# How to access values from json array

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray

I have some NSData coming back from my server that is of type Json. I would like to know how to access the values present in the json and put them into there own NSString objects.

This is what the structure of the JsonArray looks like

[image]

This is the code I am using, however my for loop only ever shows "result" and nothing else.

```
NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:csvData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
    NSLog(@"%@", jsonArray);
    if (!jsonArray) {
        NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", error);
    } else {
        for(NSDictionary *item in jsonArray) {
            NSLog(@"Item: %@", item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like your array contains dictionaries. And your dictionarys have a string as their key and another array as their value. Rest is up to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access it like that:

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in jsonArray)
{
    NSLog(@"Data: %@", dict[@"result"]);
}
```

You have dictionary in your array so you have to enumerate is and access it by key (result, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDictionary *resultDictionary = [jsonArray objectAtIndex: 0];
NSArray *resultArray = [resultDictionary objectForKey:@"result"];

for (NSString *item in resultArray)
{
    NSLog (@"item: %@",item);
}
```

You should add some (non)sense checking.

Answer (score 0):

u can access the json array like this,

```
for(NSDictionary *Mydictionary in MyJsonArray) {
   Nsstring *DataOne = [Mydictionary objectforkey@"Mykey"];
}
```

For Cheking the json node u can put the json in this site and all the node will appear properly

http://json.parser.online.fr/